# animated image drifts from center when window shrinks

Tags: javascript, html, css

There is a weather icon that is supposed to stay centered when the browser shrinks (i.e. to be displayed on mobile) but, it drifts to the right. Any ideas on how to fix it?
http://codepen.io/perrylivingston/full/JXqKWv/

```
<img id="partly_cloudy"   src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/android/512/Weather-Partly-    Cloudy-Day-icon.png">
<div style:"text-align:center" id="the_weather"></div>
<!--<h1 style="text-align:center" id="demo_data">72&deg</h1>
<h5 style="text-align:center">BOSTON, MA</h5>
<h5 style="text-align:center">PARTLY CLOUDY</h5>
<h5 style="text-align:center">22&degC</h5>-->

<button class="js-geolocation"> Use Location</button>
<div style="text-align:center"><a href="https://twitter.com/share"  class="twitter-share-button" data-text="I know the weather outside thanks to @Perryodical" data-size="large" target="_blank">Tweet</a></div>
```

CSS

```
body {
background-image: url("http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/blue-sky.jpg");
background-size: cover;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

#the_weather {
width: auto;
text-align: center;
margin: 0px auto;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #000;
} 
/*#demo_data {
padding-top: 120px;
color: #000;
}
h5 {
color: #000;
font-weight: bold;
}
*/
@-moz-keyframes floating {
 from {-moz-transform:translate(0, 1px);}
to {-moz-transform: translate(0, -10px);} 
}

@-webkit-keyframes floating{
 from {-webkit-transform:translate(0, 1px);}
to {-webkit-transform: translate(0, -10px);} 
}

#partly_cloudy {
width: 80px;
height: auto;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -2.4%;
margin-top: 30px;
-moz-animation-name:floating;
-moz-animation-duration: 1s;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-moz-animation-direction: alternate;
-moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-webkit-animation-name:floating;
-webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
 }

@font-face {
font-family: 'the_weather';
src: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/93/artill_clean_icons-webfont.eot');
src: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/93/artill_clean_icons-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/93/artill_clean_icons-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/93/artill_clean_icons-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/93/artill_clean_icons-webfont.svg#artill_clean_weather_iconsRg') format('svg');
}


i {
color: #efcc3a;
font-size: 160px;
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

#the_weather li {
display: block;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 5px;
}
/*WI portion of simpleweather.js not supported without paid subscription */
/*
.icon-0:before { content: ":"; }
.icon-1:before { content: "p"; }
.icon-2:before { content: "S"; }
.icon-3:before { content: "Q"; }
.icon-4:before { content: "S"; }
.icon-5:before { content: "W"; }
.icon-6:before { content: "W"; }
.icon-7:before { content: "W"; }
.icon-8:before { content: "W"; }
.icon-9:before { content: "I"; }
.icon-10:before { content: "W"; }
.icon-11:before { content: "I"; }
.icon-12:before { content: "I"; }
.icon-13:before { content: "I"; }
.icon-14:before { content: "I"; }
.icon-15:before { content: "W"; }
.icon-16:before { content: "I"; }
.icon-17:before { content: "W"; }
.icon-18:before { content: "U"; }
.icon-19:before { content: "Z"; }
.icon-20:before { content: "Z"; }
.icon-21:before { content: "Z"; }
.icon-22:before { content: "Z"; }
.icon-23:before { content: "Z"; }
.icon-24:before { content: "E"; }
.icon-25:before { content: "E"; }
.icon-26:before { content: "3"; }
.icon-27:before { content: "a"; }
.icon-28:before { content: "A"; }
.icon-29:before { content: "a"; }
.icon-30:before { content: "A"; }
.icon-31:before { content: "6"; }
.icon-32:before { content: "1"; }
.icon-33:before { content: "6"; }
.icon-34:before { content: "1"; }
.icon-35:before { content: "W"; }
.icon-36:before { content: "1"; }
.icon-37:before { content: "S"; }
.icon-38:before { content: "S"; }
.icon-39:before { content: "S"; }
.icon-40:before { content: "M"; }
.icon-41:before { content: "W"; }
.icon-42:before { content: "I"; }
.icon-43:before { content: "W"; }
.icon-44:before { content: "a"; }
.icon-45:before { content: "S"; }
.icon-46:before { content: "U"; }
.icon-47:before { content: "S"; }
*/
#the_weather ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

button {
display: block;
margin: 15px auto;
width: 140px;
padding: 5px;
background:#efcc3a;
color: #0;
font-weight: bold;
border: 0;
border-radius: 5px;
}
button:hover {
background-color: #ed8e0e;
}
button:active {
color: rgb(217, 217, 217);
}
.twitter-share-button {
text-align: center;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 2.5px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Javascript

```
if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
$('.js-geolocation').show(); 
} else {
$('.js-geolocation').hide();
}

$('.js-geolocation').on('click', function() {
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
 loadWeather(position.coords.latitude+','+position.coords.longitude);
 });
 });


$(document).ready(function() {
loadWeather('New York','');
});

function loadWeather(location, woeid) {
$.simpleWeather({
location: location,
woeid: woeid,
unit: 'f',
success: function(weather) {
  html = '<h2><i class="icon-'+weather.code+'"></i>    '+weather.temp+'&deg;'+weather.units.temp+'</h2>';
  html += '<ul><li>'+weather.city+', '+weather.region+'</li>';
  html += '<li class="currently">'+weather.currently+'</li>';
  html += '<li>'+weather.alt.temp+'&deg;C</li></ul>';  

  $("#the_weather").html(html);
},
error: function(error) {
  $("#the_weather").html('<p>'+error+'</p>');
 }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#partly_cloudy {
width: 80px;
height: auto;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
padding-top: 50px;
margin: 0 auto;
-moz-animation-name:floating;
-moz-animation-duration: 1s;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-moz-animation-direction: alternate;
-moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-webkit-animation-name:floating;
-webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

try this, tho there is a problem because the icon is on top of the `#the_weather` its your choice on how you design it. regards.

**UPDATE:** 
-`margin-top: 30px;` to `padding-top: 50px;` 
-icon on top of the `#the_weather`. Fixed.